# Multiple get requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, get, fetch-api

I'm new with React and APIs. I'm trying to make two get requests and assign two keys with their new values to `items` array. Here the `img` key coming from the second get request keeps overriding the whole object. So, it makes the first get request as if it doesn't exist. I need to just append the second key with the first key-values coming from the first fetch. Hope that does make sense.

```
fetch(url,{
  method: 'GET'
})
.then((response)=> response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  const newItems = responseJson.items.map(i => {
    return{
      name: i.name
    };
  })
  const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state, {
    items: newItems
  });

  console.log(newState);
  this.setState(newState);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
fetch(url2,{
  method: 'GET'
})
.then((response)=> response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
const newItems = responseJson.ebay.map(i => {
  return{
    img: i.picture.url[0]
  };
})
const newState = Object.assign(this.state, {
  items: newItems
});

  console.log(newState);
  this.setState(newState);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this for the second request:

```
const newState = {
  items: [...this.state.items, ...newItems]
}

this.setState(newState);
```

Comment: Thank you but I know what is happening, I'm just looking for way to assign the img key other than the Object.assign(). something like append.

Comment: Hey, i've changed the answer, hope it helps